# continuity equation for a fluid with variable density

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I am trying to derive the equation for buoyancy frequency in a stratified fluid and am struggling with some of the equations. I have a limited background in fluid dynamics so I basically just need someone to break down the continuity equation for me, in terms that are easily understood.

From the set of notes I am looking at:

[image]

This is the first step of the method for deriving the equation, can anyone explain this in simplistic terms?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/54309/oscillations-of-a-fluid-particle-in-a-stably-stratified-fluid/54329#54329

Comment: In very simplistic terms, this equation represents the principle of conservation of mass (no creation, no destruction of matter).

Answer (score 2):

Recall the definition the the "[material derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_derivative)"
$$
  \frac{D\rho}{Dt} := \frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t} + \vec v\cdot \nabla \rho
$$
If $\nabla\cdot\vec v = 0$ (as for incompressible flow) then the continuity equation is
$$
  \frac{D\rho}{Dt} = 0
$$
and combining these results gives what is written.

I may have misunderstood your question though.  Are you looking for the physical interpretation of these different quantities and steps?

Answer (score 1):

The continuity equation for a compressible fluid is the following: $$\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t}+\nabla\cdot(\rho\vec{v})=0$$
Divergence of the current $\rho\vec{v}$ contains the term $\rho\nabla\cdot\vec{v}$ which vanishes for incompressible fluid. The remainder is just $\frac{D\rho}{Dt}$, as joshphysics said.